# Convert into EELS

Tags: dm-script

I have a problem in batch converting image into EELS data by script.

I compared the difference between EELS data and image, the main difference is the EELS data have the tag group: "Meta Data" which contain "Format:Spectrum image" and "Signal:EELS" tags. ("Format" and "signal" are in the "Meta Data" tag group.)

Here is my code:

```
image front := GetFrontImage()
Taggroup imgtags=front.ImageGetTaggroup()
Taggroup metadata = NewTaggroup()
Taggroup tg = NewTaggroup()
number index
index = metadata.TaggroupCreateNewLabeledTag("Meta data")
index = tg.TaggroupCreateNewLabeledTag("Format")
tg.TaggroupSetIndexedTagAsString( index, "Spectrum image")
index = tg.TaggroupCreateNewLabeledTag("Signal")
tg.TaggroupSetIndexedTagAsString( index, "EELS")
metadata.TaggroupCopyTagsFrom(tg.TaggroupClone())
imgtags.TaggroupCopyTagsFrom(metadata.TaggroupClone())
```

But it returns "Format", "signal" and "Meta Data" are in the same level.

Is anyone know what's wrong in my code? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Tags/TagGroups can be confusing in scripting due to the different routes one can take (*simplified vs detailed commands*) and the type of tags (*TagLists with indexed entries vs. TagGroups with labeled entries.*)

What you want in your example is essentially:

- Create a new TagGroup (*Meta Data*)
- have two (String) sub-tags of that gorup
- Add that group to the front image

This is done in scripting:

```
TagGroup metaDataTG = newTagGroup()
metaDataTG.TagGroupSetTagAsString( "Format", "Spectrum image" )
metaDataTG.TagGroupSetTagAsString( "Signal", "EELS" )

GetFrontImage().ImageGetTagGroup().TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup( "Meta Data", metaDataTG )
```

However, you can also use the "simplest" commands here, as this is a specific tag-path (no indexed lists) you know. You can simply do:

```
image img := GetFrontImage()
img.SetStringNote( "Meta Data:Format", "Spectrum image" )
img.SetStringNote( "Meta Data:Signal", "EELS" )
```

There is one other thing worth knowing:

The MetaData tags are used by DigitalMicrograph internally a lot. Changing them by script might sometimes trigger unexpected behavior. In particular: Many plugins "read" these tags only once when an image is displayed for the first time. Hence when you add the tags by scripts to an already displayed image, it will not 'affect' DigitalMicrograph immediately. You need to close it and re-opened it.

If you want to tag any "new" image with these tags, it is better to do this before displaying the image.